# I can' t set the Authorization Bearer header after register with passport

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, http-headers, passport-jwt

I tried to save the bearer token in req.header["Authorization"]

```js
//here a tried to authenticate using jwt strategy but send "unauthorized"
app.get ("/secret", passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), (req, res) => {
    res.send ("secret");  
})
//register route authenticate local with passport after create a jwt token
app.post ("/register", (req, res) => {
    User.register (new User ({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, (err, user) => {
        if (err)
            return res.send (err);
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
            const token = "Bearer " + generateToken ({_id: user._id});
            req.header["Authorization"] = token;
            res.redirect ("/secret");
        })
    })
})
app.listen (3000);
```

> I add the token to the req.header["Authorization"], but when the res redirect to secret get route it says "Unauthorized", but when i try with postman to send manually the token through a authorization Bearer header it works

> I used passport-jwt strategy and extract method. For extract i used fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(). My question is if we can append new headers on req obj ?

Comment: This is a lot of code. Can you try to simply the code down into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I hope now is better